# how do i use python libraries in C++?

Tags: c++, python, nltk

I want to use the [nltk](http://nltk.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page) libraries in c++.

Is there a glue language/mechanism I can use to do this?

Reason:
I havent done any serious programming in c++ for a while  and want to revise NLP concepts at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also try the [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) library; which has [this capability](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/python/doc/v2/callbacks.html). This library is mainly used to expose C++ to Python, but can be used the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for nice resource. It solved several tiresome hours of me. Is there any concrete example without boost?

Comment: Would it also be possible to import third-party Python libraries (e.g. installed via pip system-wide) from within Boost.Python in C++?

Answer (score 18):

Although calling c++ libs from python is more normal - you can call a python module from c++ by bascially calling the python intepreter and have it execute the python source.
This is called [embedding](https://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html)

Alternatively the [boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) library makes it very easy.

Comment: embedding doc has moved https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/embedding.html, I've suggested an edit.

Answer (score 3):

[Pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/) can be cleanly used for this purpose.  There's an [example](http://www.pysoy.org/changeset/11/branches/pyrex-soy/Demos/embed/) in the source-code release.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried directly calling Python functions from C++, but here are some alternative ideas...

Generally, it's easier to call C++ code from a high-level language like Python than the other way around.  If you're interested in this approach, then you could create a C++ codebase and access it from Python.  You could either directly use the external API provided by python [it should be described somewhere in the Python docs] or use a tool like SWIG to automate the C++-to-Python wrapping process.

Depending on how you want to use the library, you could alternatively create Python scripts which you call from C++ with the [exec*](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exec.html) functions.