# Is it possible to call a Python module from ObjC?

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

Using PyObjC, is it possible to import a Python module, call a function and get the result as (say) a NSString?

For example, doing the equivalent of the following Python code:

```
import mymodule
result = mymodule.mymethod()
```

..in pseudo-ObjC:

```
PyModule *mypymod = [PyImport module:@"mymodule"];
NSString *result = [[mypymod getattr:"mymethod"] call:@"mymethod"];
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137/calling-python-from-a-c-program-for-distribution; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297112/how-do-i-use-python-libraries-in-c.  You can embed Python in any application.

Comment: @S.Lott This isn't a duplicate; those questions are about C++, not Objective-C. While you can use Objective-C++ to mix C++ and Objective-C, you'd have to wrap all of the C++ code in Objective-C classes yourself if you need to use them as Objective-C classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in Alex Martelli's answer (although the link in the mailing-list message was broken, it should be https://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding).. The C way of calling..

```
print urllib.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
```

- Add the Python.framework to your project (Right click `External Frameworks..`, `Add > Existing Frameworks`. The framework in in `/System/Library/Frameworks/`
- Add `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers` to your "Header Search Path" (`Project > Edit Project Settings`)

The following code should work (although it's probably not the best code ever written..)

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(){
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Py_Initialize();

    // import urllib
    PyObject *mymodule = PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString("urllib"));
    // thefunc = urllib.urlopen
    PyObject *thefunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymodule, "urlopen");

    // if callable(thefunc):
    if(thefunc && PyCallable_Check(thefunc)){
        // theargs = ()
        PyObject *theargs = PyTuple_New(1);

        // theargs[0] = "http://google.com"
        PyTuple_SetItem(theargs, 0, PyString_FromString("http://google.com"));

        // f = thefunc.__call__(*theargs)
        PyObject *f = PyObject_CallObject(thefunc, theargs);

        // read = f.read
        PyObject *read = PyObject_GetAttrString(f, "read");

        // result = read.__call__()
        PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(read, NULL);


        if(result != NULL){
            // print result
            printf("Result of call: %s", PyString_AsString(result));
        }
    }
    [pool release];
}
```

Also [this tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497) is good

Answer (score 3):

Not quite, AFAIK, but you can do it "the C way", as suggested for example in http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2004/Jan/msg00598.html -- or "the Pyobjc way" as per http://osdir.com/ml/python.pyobjc.devel/2005-06/msg00019.html (see also all other messages on that thread for further clarification).