# Can I write my apps in python and then run them from C?

Tags: python, c, interop

I need to write a client-server application. I want to write it in python, because I'm familiar with it, but I would like to know if the python code can be ran from C. I'm planning to have two C projects, one containing the server code, and one containing the client code.

Is it possible to eval the python code and run it ? Is there another way of doing this?

The bottom line is that the python code must run from C, and it must behave exactly as if ran under the python interpreter. I'm asking this now, because I don't want to waste time writing the python code just to find out later that I can't achieve this . As a sidenote, I only plan on using basic python modules ( socket,select, etc. ).

EDIT: maybe this edit is in order. I haven't embedded python in C before, and I don't know what the behaviour will be. The thing is, the server will have a select loop, and will therefore run "forever". Will C let me do that ?

EDIT2: here is why I need to do this. At school, a teacher asked us to do a pretty complex client-server app in C. I'm going to cheat, write the code in python and embed it in C.

Comment: do you mean a cross compiler of Python to C or embedding Python in C?

Comment: Isn't your teacher going to want to look at your source code? And isn't the point of the exercise to prove your knowledge of C?

Comment: I don't think "cheating" this way is really a good idea.

Comment: It's not cheating, it's a waste of effort -- you can write the most complex web server or web client you want in pure Python.

Comment: Indeed, it will be cheating and I don't think your teacher will appreciate. In the real-world, you are welcome to try the best solution. Not in school. As a typical example, in the real-world, the best solution is often not to program, but to reuse an existing program. That would not be an acceptable answer to a programming assignment.

Comment: I know how to do it in C, but it will take a lot more time.

Comment: The teacher/tutor will want to look at your code. I would expect him/her to want at least. And then it will be very obvious.

Comment: I won't be having any python files in my project. I won't have any python string in my code. I plan on uploading them somewhere :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's a nice tutorial for doing exactly that http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497

Comment: This is a really good article. I would not actually do this in this particular case but nevertheles, you answered it correctly I believe. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's called embedding Python -- it's well covered in the Python docs.  See https://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html

See [how do i use python libraries in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297112/how-do-i-use-python-libraries-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run the Python code from C by embedding the interpreter in your program. You can expose portions of your C code to Python and call your exposed C code from Python as if they were normal Python functions.

A good start is the [Embedding](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) section in the Python docs. Also have a look at the [article linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792924/can-i-write-my-apps-in-python-and-then-run-them-from-c/792935#792935) by cobbal.