# is it possible to call python methods from a C program?

Tags: python, c, embedding

I remember seeing somewhere that you could call python methods from inside C using

```
#include "python.h"
```

But I can't seem to find the source for this or any examples.

How can I call python methods from inside a C program?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297112/how-do-i-use-python-libraries-in-c

Comment: odd... I must've missed it when I searched for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ext/callingPython.html) a doc item from the python site about extending C with python functionality

[Here's](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ext/simpleExample.html) the start of the documentation (where it refers to python.h) where you can extend Python with C functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [http://docs.python.org/c-api](http://docs.python.org/c-api/)